# Upgrade to 22.10 failed; apt error

Tags: do-release-upgrade

Tried sudo do-release-upgrade to get 22.10 (from 22.04.1) today. It aborted. Now I have some errors with my sources.

sudo apt update:

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

No idea how to fix this. Can anyone offer some advice? Everything else still works for now.

Thanks.

Edit (Apologies for not posting enough info):

I commented out an extra line in sources.list and the error went away:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse
```

I've made sure all *.list files in sources.list.d are returned to jammy.

sudo apt upgrade:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Try Ubuntu Pro beta with a free personal subscription on up to 5 machines.
Learn more at https://ubuntu.com/pro
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Hopefully this is enough. Also, I've just read that Kinetic is being offered as a gradual upgrade. Guess I missed that and should have waited.

Comment: When giving commands and output, please add the whole output, not bits and pieces. Edit your question with this correction. Also add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` as well as the contents of any other `.list` file in `/etc/apt` and its subdirectories. Also add the output of `sudo apt upgrade`. Your system must be up-to-date before attempting a release upgrade.

Comment: Yeah. Shortly after I posted I checked my sources.list file and there was an extra entry that didn’t have a signed-by statement. That problem is fixed now. Not sure if I’ll run into any more problems this caused, but for now all seems well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My edit above reposted as an answer.

An extra line without the signed-by statement was added to /etc/apt/sources.list. Removing/commenting it did the trick.

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src [arch=amd64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-automatic-2018.gpg] http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main universe restricted multiverse
```